# What do these properties mean in Mono.Cecil?

Tags: .net, mono, mono.cecil

I am using Lokad shared libraries, which in turn depends on Mono.Cecil.

I am a little confused what the following properties mean (they are to do with .NET internals and thus have equivalent .NET internals):

- PackingSize (they are to do with types as it is in TypeDefinition).
- Mvid (in ModuleDefinition).
- ExplicitThis (something to do with the this keyword I know, but in
  MethodDefinition).
- CallingConvention.
- GetSentinel (a method which returns int in MethodReference).
- RVA.
- SemanticsAttribute.
- IsHideBySig.

Any idea what these mean/do?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not too familiar with Cecil, but the majority of those items are related to the IL file.  Here are some answers - all taken from Serge Lidin's book: Expert .Net 2.0 IL Assembler.

- Packing Size = The alignment factor in bytes. Must be set to 0 or a power of 2 from 1 to 128. (in the class layout metadata table) (p122)
- Mvid = globally unique identifier, assigned to the module as it is generated (or module version id).  (in the module metadata table) (p105)
- Explicit This = Method call signature.  The first explicitly specified parameter is the instance pointer.  The ILAsm keywork is explicit. (p159)
- CallingConvention = the first byte of a signature identifies the type of the signature, which for historical reasons is called the calling convention of the signature. (ex: default, vararg, field, localsig, property, unmgd, hasthis, explicitthis) p158-159
- GetSentinel = most likely has to do with the sentinel modifier, which signifies the beginning of optional arguments supplied for a vararg method call. (p152)
- RVA = Relative virtual address: the address of an item once it has been loaded into memory, with the base address of the image file subtracted from it - in other words, the offset of an item within the image file loaded into memory. (p42)
- SemanticsAttribute - most likely something to do with the MethodSemantics table, which connects events and properties with their associated methods and provides information regarding the type of association.  A Semantic can be a setter, getter, other (property) or addon, removeon or fire (event) p317
- IsHideBySig - the method hides all methods of the parent classes that have a matching signature and name (as opposed to having a matching name only).  p188